# fetch API doesn't show exact error in catch, if URL is incorrect

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, fetch

JavaScript **fetch API** doesn't returns proper error text if URL is incorrect. It always returns fail to fetch error in *catch* statement.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  fetch("https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/incorrecturl")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => alert(error.toString())) // Here i need proper error message, instead of "failed to fetch".
}
```

Comment: Why not just alert a custom message rather than the error it returns?

Comment: but how can i find that is incorrect url. If it returns 404 or 500 error means i can identify.

Comment: @shanmu_92 you are not getting server error because the server is not configured of using a web service.
if you want to see the error then you need to download the extension on google chrome browser *Allow-Control-Allow-Origin* add your URL in this extension. 
then run your script then you get a proper server error.

Thanks

Comment: By running your code snippet i am getting this error 
`unexpected end of json input`

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In dev tools an error mentioning `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` turns up but that is not returned either from catch nor in the response

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myRequest = new Request('https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/incorrecturl');
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

OR

```
fetch('https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/incorrecturl').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

refs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status

Comment: What script error do you get exactly? This is also how I handle things in my app. @shanmu_92

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`  @BhanwarChaudhary